# (#200) requires extended permission publish_actions

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

```
if (session == null){
Log.i("dd", "session value in winLoose 1");
session = new Session(this);
Session.setActiveSession(session);
} else if (session.isOpened()) 
        {
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        } 

            Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback()
            {
                public void onCompleted(Response response)
                {
                        FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                        if (error != null) Log.d("fb","error"); else Log.d("fb","Success"); } };
Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(session, bitmap, callback);
request.executeAsync();
```

My session is opened When I run my above code & when I am trying to post my screenshot to FB via this code. Then this code Toast me `(#200)` requires extended permission publish_actions

Comment: private static final String PERMISSION = "publish_actions"; like this while login

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30758641/4990308 try this link

Comment: Please heck out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080255/facebook-publish-action-permission-not-working-for-posting

Comment: You need to ask user for publish permission,please refer this document ,https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/permissions

Comment: I had found the solution, Facebook do not allow all permissions for developers, So it should be requested to Facebook  to provide particular permission via going in status and review in developers console. Facebook will review app first, then after 2-3 days they allow to access that requested permission.

Answer (score 1):

I have found my Answer. My app has not permission for publish_actions. So my FB App needs to go in review to Facebook, So that they will permit the permissions for publish_actions.
Thank you very much for your efforts

Comment: Hi! i have the same issue, how much time took your app for get the permissions for publish_actions?

Answer (score 0):

```
private  final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {
            "publish_actions", "email", "user_birthday","read_stream", "user_photos"
    };
```

Pass this permissions during Login.

Comment: This is not working in my code. Permissions are not appending/adding   :(  Is there any another solution

Comment: Where you are adding these permission?

Comment: When I perform login:

session.openForPublish(new  Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(mStatusCallback)
     .setPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_friends", "public_profile", "email","publish_actions")));

Answer (score 0):

give permissions when you use `findViewById`

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) this.findViewById(R.id.login_button);

loginButton.setReadPermissions("publish_actions", "email", "user_birthday");  //Add extra permissions here
```